# Is it possible for the assert_eq macro to show a diff when two strings aren't equal?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, macros, assert, rust-cargo

I'm writing some tests for a language tokenizer and I'm comparing a JSON-serialized version of the tokenization produced by the tokenizer with a serialization of a known-good tokenization.  So I have some tests like this:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_tokenize() {
    let actual_token_json = /* string */;
    let expected_token_json = /* string */;

    assert_eq!(actual_token_json, expected_token_json);
}
```

However, when those tests fail, `cargo test` just says that the JSON strings weren't equal and prints them both out, which isn't that useful.  Since the JSON strings are both pretty-printed, it would be more helpful if `cargo test` printed out a line diff of the two strings.  Is there any way I could do this?

***Update***:
Someone edited the title of this post but deleted an important piece of information: I'm looking for a *line* diff when *two strings* aren't equal.  One of the answers I'm seeing here is for the more general question of getting a *line **and** character* diff of the debug representations of two values when they're not equal.  That's either more than I need or not what I need.  For example, the diff of the debug representations of two strings won't give me a line diff but a large, convoluted character diff (since the lines show up in the debug representation as escaped "\n" tokens).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but not with the `assert_eq` macro provided by the standard library<sup>†</sup>.  You could use the [`pretty_assertions`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101180410/https://crates.io/crates/pretty_assertions) crate which was designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

[image: diff]

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, the built-in macro could take more than two arguments to provide more information about the assertion by extending it with a custom message.  So technically, if you provide some sort of diff'ing implementation yourself or an external one, which is either `Display` or `Debug`, you could then pass it to the macro.  Strictly speaking in some ways this macro is also usable for such a thing.

Comment: Wow, that's a really nice display for the diff; the library (or version) I use is not nearly as nice, I'll need to switch/upgrade!

Comment: This is useful but, as it turns out, it doesn't work for my original question.  I'm looking for a line diff when two strings aren't equal, not a character diff of two debug representations when two values aren't equal.  With `pretty_assertions`, I get a big mess when two strings are diffed because newlines show up as "\n" escape sequences.

Answer (score 4):

See the update in my post as to why `pretty_assertions` doesn't quite work for my particular problem.  Instead, I ended up just using the `difference` library that `pretty_assertions` uses internally.  I just made a wrapper struct for `difference::Changeset` so that I could override its `fmt::Display` implementation:

```
fn prefix_lines(prefix: &str, lines: &str) -> String {
    lines
        .lines()
        .map(|i| [prefix, i].concat())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join("\n")
}

pub struct Diff(difference::Changeset);

impl Diff {
    pub fn new(left: &str, right: &str) -> Self {
        Self(difference::Changeset::new(left, right, "\n"))
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Diff {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for d in &self.0.diffs {
            match *d {
                difference::Difference::Same(ref x) => {
                    write!(f, "{}{}", prefix_lines(" ", x), self.0.split)?;
                }
                difference::Difference::Add(ref x) => {
                    write!(f, "\x1b[92m{}\x1b[0m{}", prefix_lines("+", x), self.0.split)?;
                }
                difference::Difference::Rem(ref x) => {
                    write!(f, "\x1b[91m{}\x1b[0m{}", prefix_lines("-", x), self.0.split)?;
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Then I just have a macro, as in the `pretty_assertions` implementation, that creates an instance of that struct and string formats it inside of a panic message when the assertion fails.